# While running suits using testng.xml getting null pointer Exception , While able to Run Individual tests case WITH TESTNG

Tags: testng

i created the Three suites while trying to run all of them using Testng.xml getting Nullpointer Exception. Mentioned after the code of all three suites.xml code and Testng.xml code. Please let me know if you findout why this null pointer Exception is coming.

---

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

            <Suite name="SuiteA">


                    <Test name="Test CaseA1">

                                <Classes>
                                <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                                </Classes>

                    </Test>

                    <Test name="Test CaseA2">
                                <Classes>
                                <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA2" />
                                </Classes>
                    </Test>



            </Suite>
```

---

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
        <Suite name="SuiteB">
                <Test name="TestCaseB1">
                        <Classes>
                         <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
                        </Classes>
                </Test>

                <Test name="TestCaseB2">
                        <Classes>
                        <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB2" />
                        </Classes>
                </Test>
        </Suite>
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <Suite name="SuiteC">
                <Test name="TestCaseC1">
                        <Classes>
                        <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC1" />
                        </Classes>
                </Test>
                <Test name="TestCaseC2">
                        <Classes>
                        <Class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC2" />
                        </Classes>
               </Test>
    </Suite>
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="Suite Name"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />

            </suite-files>


    </suite>
```

> org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:320)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:179)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
>         ... 3 more

Comment: How are you executing those tests? Using Maven or other method?

Comment: by right click on the testng.xml file and run as TestNG

Comment: Are those cases inside a project that uses Maven, or could use it?

Comment: @ArpanSaini could you confirm if the above shared file is as is used by you?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski : No i've not use Maven yet.

Comment: @nullpointer : Hi , I didn't get you . you mean to say the above code i have written in the description ?? Yes that's the same code I'm using . i have copy paste it here

Comment: @Arpan Saini then probably the lower case should help. The tag names are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use correct tag's name probably -

```
<!-- Note the lowercase change to tag names -->

<suite name="SuiteB">
    <test name="TestCaseB1">
        <classes>
            <class   name="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
        </classes>
```

You can find them documented here - 
http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php. Being XML tags they mostly follow lowercase with hyphens.

Comment: I think i have used the write tags , do u see any discrepancy above

Comment: @ArpanSaini - you are using the uppercase as `<Test>`, which should be `<test>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing bro, it worked now , even i was using the upper case for classes and class tags , It worked and the correct code goes here

Comment: Thanks a ton bro :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working perfectly to run Multiple suites using selenium.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteA"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestA1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestA2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>



    </suite>

    ************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteB"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestB1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestB2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteB.TestCaseB2" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>


    </suite>

    ***************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="SuiteC"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


                 <test name="TestC1" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC1" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>

                 <test name="TestC2" allow-return-values="true">
                         <classes>
                           <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                                 <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteC.TestCaseC2" />
                         </classes>
                 </test>


    </suite>

    ********************************

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
    <suite name="TestNG Dadadriver suite"  > 
    <!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 


            <suite-files>
                   <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
                   <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />

            </suite-files>


    </suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your Before and After annotations(BeforeTest, BeforeMethod, BeforeSuite, etc) add (alwaysRun = true), that might be the solution.

It worked for me.
Although I was having issues when I was using Groups in TestNG XML coupled with One class.
[image]